# 3d interactive pie chart offline

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I want to constract a 3d interactive pie chart. Firstly I use google charts but unfortunately this doesn't work offline. I used charts from jpgraph, jscharts  and rgraph but doesn't have the effect that I want. I want a graph which must be free, work offline and has approximately the same appearance with  google graph. Any advice?
Thanks in advance!

Important I want to use results from my db. I write this code but dont work:

```
data: [{
            name: 'Present',
            y: <?php 
              while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){

                echo $row2["COUNT(*)"];



                }
        }, {
            name: 'absentees',
            y: <?php 
              while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)){

                echo $row1["COUNT(*)"];



                }
```

I have those queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM staff s, work w, absence a 
WHERE s.id=a.id_staff 
AND s.id_work=w.id 
AND w.name='sales manager' 
AND a.name='disease'

SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM staff s, work w, absence a 
    WHERE s.id=a.id_staff 
    AND s.id_work=w.id 
    AND w.name='sales manager'
    AND a.name='vacation'
```

I try this but doesnt work

```
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Absent',
        data: [
            ['Absent Illness',  <?php





                   while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)){
                     while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
                    $row['COUNT(*)']=$row2['COUNT(*)'] - $row1['COUNT(*)'];
                    echo $row["COUNT(*)"];


                    }
                    }
                    ?>],
            ['Absent Vacation', 
            <?php

                   while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)){


                    echo $row1["COUNT(*)"];


                    }
                    ?>]



        ]
    }]
});
```

Comment: In what form do you receive your data? Here is simple example of pie chart using data from external source: http://jsfiddle.net/ox50bLbn/.

Answer (score 0):

Please use highchart because it provide the  varrious type of charts and you can also use it offline mode also. https://www.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 0):

Let me guide to display mysql results onto the pie chart.

    `function functionname() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'POST API LINK',
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                    title : {
                        text : "A suitable title"
                    },
                    animationEnabled : true,
                    zoomEnabled : false,
                    data : [ {
                        type : "pie",
                        dataPoints : [ {
                            y : data.active,
                            indexLabel : "Active part=" + data.active
                        }, {
                            y : data.Inactive,
                            indexLabel : "Inactive part=" + data.Inactive
                        },
                        ]
                    } ]
                });
                chart.render();
            },
            error : function() {
                alert('sorry!Somthing went wrong in Pie chart');
            }
        });
    }`

This is how you display MySQL results. 
Here In data,I am getting active and inactive value from my DB.

For the UI, Please check this [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/).
Kindly let me know if you have any queries.